# stView.el is undefined while testing Backbone view with jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine, requirejs, jasmine-jquery

I'm using Jasmine for unit testing to test an application with Backbone.js (and it's the first time that I'm working with them both so I'm a little bit stuck :/ ) 
Here is my Backbone view

```js
define(['jquery','backbone','underscore','handelbars','models/story','text!templates/story.html',
  'controllers/storyController'], 
function($, Backbone, _,handelbars, story,storyTemplate,ctrl){
 var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#main',
  events:{
   'click .close-story' : 'closeStory',
  }
        // Some functions
 });
 return View;
});
```

and the spec of Jasmine

```js
define(['views/storyView'],function (storyView) {
  describe("Testing the Story View ",function () {
    var stView;
    beforeEach(function(){
      stView=new storyView({id:1});
      stView.render();
    })
    it("Test if el is defined and trigger the click ",function () {
      expect(stView.el).toBeDefined(); 
    })
  })
})
```

Thank you :)

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting? There is no code matching `myView.render().el` as mentioned in title. Why are you clicking the button in test before `expect(stView.$el.find('.addbtn')).toBeDefined();`? Why do you need `var self = this;` in the shared code? Why are you using `$(self.el)` instead of `self.$el`?
 In short, please cleanup your code, post proper error and if possible create a [mcve]

Comment: @TJ Thank you for answering, and I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough, I edited my question  and the code I hope it's readable now. PS: I'm not the one who coded the view, I'm working only on tests with jasmine. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Still you haven't shared the code that tries to access `el` property of `render` method as you mentioned in the error in title: `myView.render().el`. So the code causing the issue is not present in question, and the content of render function is also not there in question... So we can't figure out what's the problem without seeing the code...

Comment: myView refers to stView (I wrote it the title using myView just to make it general) and the code is in the expect of spec published, I hope it's clear now, sorry again  :/

Comment: @MariamaMariama Your title states that the issue is with `stView.render().el` yet your test tests `expect(stView.el).toBeDefined()`. On the basis of the title, I'd expect the test to be `expect(stView.render().el).toBeDefined()`. It is still not clear what the problem is exactly, given the inconsistency between the title and code you show. Answers will also most likely depend on the implementation of `render()`, which as TJ pointed out already, you do not show.

Comment: @Louis, you are right, I edited it, the question is not about the implementation of render() but accessing to stView.el from spec of Jasmine.   I'm sorry again :/

Answer (score 0):

You have hardcode `el: '#main'` in the view constructor.
This will evaluate when the AMD module is loaded.
And when you run jasmine unit tests, I don't think this element of your application is available in Jasmine test page, unless you have mocked it somehow. You can test this via putting a break point on the constructor and inspecting the DOM.

For the existing code to work, you should attach a dummy element on whatever DOM jasmine is using to run your tests before loading the module containing view definition.

On the other hand, It's better to remove the hardcoded `el: '#main'` (You can tell the developer that it's a very bad coding practice) and pass the element reference while creating view instance, so you can do

```
new storyView({id:1, el : $('<div/>'}); // dummy element for test
```

Comment: Thank you for responding :) but I need that the element with "main" as id to be loaded so I can compile some handelbars code 
PS : a div with id="main" existe in a index.html (it's a file in the root of the project)
PPS: the index is always loaded before all the views. Thank you !

Comment: @MariamaMariama As far as I know Jasmine is for unit testing, and unit tests won't create the DOM structure of your application. So I don't think jasmine will load you're index.html. You have to mock it

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't find how to mock it, all I found is how to mock an object not an html,then I tried to load it using fixture ""jasmine.getFixtures().load("../../index.html");"" in the beforeEach of the spec and using ""define(['text!../../index.html'],function()"" at the head of the spec but no success even if I found the file loaded if I check the network tab while inspecting errors in chrome. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I don't know how to load fixtures in jasmine either, answers to this question might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/12715207/2333214